# Keyboard class implementation in windows application

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I want to implement a Keyboard class like below;

```
class Keyboard
{
public:
    Keyboard();
    ~Keyboard();
    bool IsKeyDown(Key);
    bool IsKeyUp(Key);
    void SetPressedKey(int);
    void SetReleasedKey(int);
private:
    Key pressedKey;
    Key releasedKey;
};
```

Key is an enum like below;

```
enum Key
{
    A,
    Enter,
    Up,
    Down
};
```

Here is the window callback function;

```
case WM_KEYDOWN:
    kb.SetPressedKey(wParam);
    break;
case WM_KEYUP:
    kb.SetReleasedKey(wParam);
    break;
```

First of all, my design can be completely wrong. If it's an acceptable design, there are some questions that I couldn't answer. Can value of the pressedKey be overwritten if user presses two buttons at the same time and how can I determine if user uses combinations like CTRL+C. The other question is I couldn't find a way to make a relationship between wParam's value and enum keys' indexes.

Comment: Instead of pressedKey you could have an array of all keys available and keep track of those that are in pressed state since more than one key can be pressed simultaneously.

Comment: Do you mean if user holds down two buttons this array will have two elements?

Comment: E.g. in your class:
   `bool keyState[256];`

And in SetPressedKey:
   `keyState[wParam] = true;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the implementation of this class is unnecessary and should be removed. You are re-implementing functionality that the operating system already provides. If you want to know the state of a key, simply call [`GetKeyState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301.aspx).

You may choose to wrap up the low-level Win32 API `GetKeyState` with your class. But do not store the information as state in your class. When you need to know the state of a key, i.e. when implementing `IsKeyDown()` and `IsKeyUp()`, call `GetKeyState`.

Another good reason for this is that you cannot guarantee that all keyboard messages will arrive in your window. Somebody may press a key whilst a different window is active, and then switch to your program. At that point, your attempt to track state using keyboard messages will break down because you never got the key down message. However, `GetKeyState` will work.

That said, if you need to know the instantaneous state, outside of a window procedure, then you would use [`GetAsyncKeyState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293.aspx) rather than `GetKeyState`. Only you fully understand the purpose of this class and so are in a position to make that decision.

Comment: So it's not needed to store the pressedKey data because OS is already storing it?

Comment: Correct. And what's more, the OS will get it right, and there are scenarios where your approach cannot be correct.

Comment: And if you *think* you want GetAsyncKeyState, [think harder](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/11/30/272262.aspx).

Comment: @Eric in a game loop without a window proc then GetKeyState is no use

Answer (score 2):

Windows already keeps track of all this information. If you want to know if a key is currently pressed, `GetKeyState`. This queries the keyboard state tied to the current message. So for example it's accurate to use `GetKeyState` to know if CTRL was pressed inside a `WM_KEYDOWN` message.

There is also `GetAsyncKeyState`, if you want to query the keyboard state "right now", rather than the state when the current message was generated.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of your design I personally would try to make it a bit better by having it as a set of Key object and have the keys maintain their own state. That way you can model multiple key presses. The example (incomplete and not tested!) shows the idea.

```
class Keyboard
{
public:
    Keyboard();
    ~Keyboard();
    bool isPressed(Key);
    void pressKey(int);  // or Key
    void releaseKey(int);
private:
    std::set<Key> keys;
};

class Keyboard
{
public:
    // define your comparison operators to use std::set or else write a comparator.
    Key(uint32 id);
    ~Key();
    bool 
    void setPressed();
    void setReleased();
    bool isPressed() const;
private:
    uint32 keyId;
    bool pressed;
};
```

In order to relate the windows key values to `Key` objects you could build a factory to return the keyIds that you need. Your KeyIds could be an enum or just re-use the windows values. As long as they are unique and your *application* understands then then there is no point in being restrictive.